# Video thumbnails Issue in SERP just for Unicode URLs

Tags: url, search-engine-indexing, search-results, video

I tested many times and I made sure that Google not interested to show my thumbnails of video when I have URLs with non-English characters.

When I rollback canonical and internal links to English URLs, The problem solved.
Now I want to now what is the reason?

I think Google can not detect the page is a video page when I use non-English URL and Google can detect the page is a video page when I don't use non-English URL!

The source code of both version of URLs are same.

Can anyone say what is the problem?

**To see live example:**

Search :

> واکنش والدین به پخش آهنگ ساسی در مدارس ! tamasha.com

And see image below:

```
i.imgur.com/BrOlcm8.jpg
```

And search :

> آموزش سئو : نحوه ایجاد ساختار صفحات SEO-Friendly - محسن طاوسی

And see image below:

```
i.imgur.com/FxUq3ix.jpg
```